# What limits Kate text editor search feature?

Tags: search, editors, kate

I am fairly new with Kate, started to use it, because it's search feature shows the number of occurrences found. But now I found a problem with search. It works fine for few line files (few hundreds) but with larger files it stops search without any clear reason. If I run same search on same data, it happen that number of found occurrences is different than on previous search attempt. Is this a bug?

[image]

Kate version - 15.12.3

**Update**

I use Kate on Ubuntu 16.04 and it seems like with apt-get 15.12.3 Kate version is latest. I also tried to download *.Appimage file from Kate  website, to get something newer - it is now 16.08.0. Though the same problem. Here two screen shots. Please note the number of found occurrences different, though data in open file is the same. Also please note this file not saved on disk. I just opened new file and insert some text in it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you've found a bug — or maybe an intentional limitation (e.g., maybe there is a time limit, to keep a search with a lot of matches from hanging kate).

Appears to be removed in later versions, though; I used 17.08.3 with a file:

```
hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. 
hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world. hello world, goodbye world.
```

with that repeated for 32,768 lines. Kate 17.08.3 "Find All" found 393,216 matches, which is all of them. Doubling the lines again, it found 786,432.

I'd suggest using one of the command-line text processing tools (e.g., grep/sed/awk or Perl).

Comment: Hi, please see my update. Version change not solved it. How did you get 17 version (latest available is 16). Are you compiled it from source code? As about command line text processors - they are nice but not convenient for me. I often copy paste few thousand lines text and check with regex (no need to save the data). I still have few options like windows notepad++, but it needs windows. Eclipse search is nice, but it needs the file to be saved on disk. The limitation on Kate seems strange because it is silent (no alert) and very small threshold (I see it in just 2000 lines text)

Comment: @Pavlo 17.08.3 is the version currently in Debian testing. I'm not sure why they haven't updated the AppImage. Building from source is probably non-trivial, since it'll need a bunch of KDE libs (and actually, the find is part of KTextEditor...)